# A C++ Program that reads the marks obtained of ten students out of 100. It also computes the average; lowest and highest marks

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

A C++ Program that reads the marks obtained of ten students out of 100. It also computes the average; lowest and highest marks. Then shows the difference of marks of every student from the average marks.

Here goes the code written by me for this problem. But when I run the program I am getting value of average and low marks as 0 and also the difference of average and marks obtained is not coming the same what I needed it to be. Can someone explain me that where I am lacking, I am a novice in programming.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int marks[10],avg=0,high,low;
cout<<"Enter the marks of 10 students:";
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
  cin>>marks[i];
  if(marks[i]>marks[i+1]){
    low=marks[i+1];
  }
  else 
  {
    low=marks[i];
  }
  if(marks[i]>marks[i+1]){
    high=marks[i];
  }
  else 
  {
    high=marks[i+1];
  }
  
  avg=avg+(marks[i])/100;
}
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
cout<<"Marks obtained by "<<i+1<<" student:"<<marks[i]<<endl;
  cout<<"Difference of marks of student "<<i+1<<" with average marks:";
  
  if((avg-marks[i])>0){cout<<avg-marks[i];}
  else{cout<<marks[i]-avg;}
  cout<<endl<<endl;
  }
cout<<"Lowest marks:"<<low<<endl;
cout<<"Highest marks:"<<high<<endl;
cout<<"Average marks:"<<avg<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if(marks[i]>marks[i+1])` comparing entered value `marks[i]` with 'will be entered' value `marks[i+1]`, that's a new future predicting algo...

Comment: Sorry, but I could not understand what you are trying to say. Please, can you elaborate that how this problem could be solved?@user3124812

Comment: Lets start from the beginning, `i==0`, `cin>>marks[i]` and user entered `42`. So `marks[i]` is `42`. What is a value of `marks[i+1]` ?

Comment: You need to first init the array and then compare, you are comparing not yet initialized variables. also you sum 10 numbers but divide by 100 each time..

Answer (score 0):

It can be done even better, try to improve it, it's a good practice.

first you need to get all the input separately,
then you init your low and high as the first number, then you go through the array and if number is higher or lower from the current value of high/low you update you high/low.

your compare was incorrect you compare each two numbers. in case of 10 5 4 3 your max will be 4.

#include
using namespace std;

```
int main(){
int marks[10],avg=0,sum =0 ,high,low=;
cout<<"Enter the marks of 10 students:";
for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
  cin>>marks[j];
 }
 high = marks[0],low = marks[0];
 for(int i=1;i<10;i++){ 
  if (marks[i] > high){
      high = marks[i];
  }
  else if(marks[i] < low){
      low = marks[i];
  }
  sum=sum+(marks[i]);
 }
 avg = sum /10;
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
cout<<"Marks obtained by "<<i+1<<" student:"<<marks[i]<<endl;
  cout<<"Difference of marks of student "<<i+1<<" with average marks:";
  
  if((avg-marks[i])>0){cout<<avg-marks[i];}
  else{cout<<marks[i]-avg;}
  cout<<endl<<endl;
  }
cout<<"Lowest marks:"<<low<<endl;
cout<<"Highest marks:"<<high<<endl;
cout<<"Average marks:"<<avg<<endl;
return 0;
}
```